# SQL - How to find difference betweeen same Column

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have the following table which describes file action in each action for a particular request. I need to find the net files present in each request.

```
req_id | action_id | file_action | file_name
1          1            A             1.txt
1          2            D             1.txt
1          3            A             2.txt
1          4            D             2.txt
1          5            A             3.txt
1          6            D             3.txt
1          7            A             4.txt
```

Expected Output

```
req_id | action_id | file_action | file_name
1          7            A             4.txt
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what *difference between same column* or *net files present in each request* means, but based on your expected output this is a simple `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM yourtable ORDER BY action_id DESC`. If that doesn't suit your needs, then [edit] your question to be more specific about what your requirements are in terms of the table and post your attempt at writing the SQL yourself that isn't working as you expect.

Comment: The above table describes each File action done on a Particular  request. And this table as the user done actions on a request .File action **A** means **Added** and **D** means **Deleted**. So here net Files names means at a point of time how many files are present in system for a given request id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you need the records that only have file_action = 'A' you can:

```
select * from table1 as t1 where t1.file_action = 'A'
and not exists (select 1 from table1 as t2
                  where t2.file_Action='D'
                    and t1.file_name = t2.file_name
                 )
```

Comment: There was an error instead of that "where" it was "and"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.req_id, t1.action_id, t1.file_action, t1.file_name
from mytable t1
where t1.file_action = "A"
and not exists
(
select 1
from mytable t2
where t2.req_id = t1.req_id
and t2.file_name = t1.file_name
and t2.file_action = "D"
)
```